# Can we replace a char with its decimal escape code?

Tags: eclipse, string

```
str = "tést";
```

I want to replace above é with its decimal escape code`&#233;`.
I tried below,

```
str=str.replaceAll("é","&#233;");
```

but failed to run build because, worning: é is unmappable character for encoding utf8.

So, Is there any way to find a char with decimal point 233 from a string and replace it.

Answer for below comment:

here is the **build warning**

```
D:\workspace\ProName\build\src\com\Pro\ps\ProRetrieve.java:381: warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
 [javac]            array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("�", "&#233;");
[javac] 

                                        ^
```

Here when we run build it would create **jar** file. We are running this jar file using .bat file

below is the code for bat file to run jar

```
@ ECHO OFF
D:
cd D:\workspace\ProName\build\target
java -jar ProApp.jar
```

Comment: _"failed to run build"_ -- please update your post to include the actual compiler error message, and also show the command line you used to invoke the compiler (`javac`).  It is likely there is a mismatch between the source file encoding and what the compiler is expecting.

Comment: @ ECHO OFF
D:
cd D:\workspace\ProName\build\target
java -jar ProApp.jar

Comment: Hi Jim Garrison, I have updated with requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source file is encoded in the Windows default, which is probably Windows-1252 (ISO-8859-1) but the javac command is expecting UTF-8.  Ideally you would change your file to UTF-8 but you can also specify the option `-encoding ISO-8859-1` on the javac command line.

In an IDE you will need to find where you set the source encoding, and I don't remember offhand where that is set in Eclipse and don't have access to my Eclipse system right now.

Comment: Many Thanks Jim. I did follow "Preferences>General>Workspace and select UTF-8 as the Text File Encoding . This should set the encoding for all the resources in your workspace" and worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`javac` is the compiler, so it's the *compiler* that is choking on the character, not anything at runtime. You've tried to replace it with the way HTML escapes characters, not the way Java wants you to [embed Unicode values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) into its source files, such as with `String str = "t\u00e9st";` where `\uXXXX` uses 4 hexadecimal digits to represent the Unicode value of the character.